# Changing form from edit mode to new mode run time error 2105

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am trying to create a form that will do a search of first name and last name. If the record is found then edit the found record. If the record is not found then create a new record.

The search for an existing record works great. When I can't find a record and I try to switch the form mode to New and create a new record I am currently getting the run time error 2105 You can't go to the specified record. I have been working on this for about a week to no avail. I am hoping I can get some help.

```
Private Sub cmdSearch_Click()
Dim strFixID As String
Dim lMaxCustNum As Long
Dim lMaxId As Long

Set frmCurrentForm = Screen.ActiveForm

Stop

DoCmd.SetWarnings False
strTable = "tblMarketBulletinNew"

Me.FilterOn = False
Me.Filter = "[FirstName1] like '" & Me.txtSearchFirstName & "*' AND [LastName1] like '" & 
Me.txtSearchlastName & "*'"
Me.FilterOn = True

If Me.Recordset.recordCount > 0 Then
'If record exists
        DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acFirst
       'Change Default value for Action for existing record
        Me.txtOrigSignUpDate.Locked = True
        Me.txtAction.Locked = False
        Me.txtExpirationDate.Locked = True

        
    Else
    'No record exists so create new record
        Me.FilterOn = False
        Me.DataEntry = True
        Me.AllowEdits = True
        Me.AllowAdditions = True
        Me.AllowDeletions = True
        'To prevent error the changed you were requested were unsucessful
        lMaxId = DMax("ID", strTable) + 1
        strFixID = "ALTER TABLE " & strTable & " ALTER COLUMN ID COUNTER(" & lMaxId & ",1);"
        Debug.Print strFixID
      'DoCmd.RunSQL strFixID
        
        lMaxCustNum = DMax("NewCustNum", strTable) + 1
        Me.Recordset.AddNew
        Me.txtCustNumber = lMaxCustNum
       

        Me.SetFocus
        DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec



        Me.txtAction.DefaultValue = "New"
        Me.txtAction.Locked = True
        Me.lblRenSignupDate.Visible = False
        Me.txtrenSignupDate.Visible = False
        Me.txtStatus.DefaultValue = "Active"
        Me.txtExpirationDate.Locked = True
        'Add First and Last name already entered
        Me.txtFirstName1 = txtSearchFirstName
        Me.txtLastName1 = txtSearchlastName
        Me.txtOrigSignUpDate = Date
        
      End If

DoCmd.SetWarnings True

End Sub
```

Comment: At what line is the exception thrown?

Comment: Also, I assume this code is associated with your form? That is, "Me" refers to the form?

Comment: DoCmd.gotorecord, , acNewrec

Comment: Yes the me is the current form

Comment: If I comment out the DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec line I get the error message The changes you requested to the table were not successful because they would create duplicates values.  When I get to the last textbox and try and enter the record

Comment: The values I am picking are not duplicates

Comment: _The values I am picking are not duplicates_ ... but they are, or at least one field value is. There is no other scenario that can raise this error.

Answer (score 1):

Either use the form to add the record:

```vb
    lMaxCustNum = DMax("NewCustNum", strTable) + 1
    DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
    Me.txtCustNumber = lMaxCustNum
    '...    
    Me.txtFirstName1 = txtSearchFirstName
    Me.txtLastName1 = txtSearchlastName
    Me.txtOrigSignUpDate = Date
    ' Save record.
    Me.Dirty = False
```

or use the RecordsetClone:

```vb
Dim Records As DAO.Recordset
Set Records = Me.RecordsetClone   

Records.AddNew
Records!CustNumber.Value = lMaxCustNum
' ...
Records!FirstName1.Value = Me!txtSearchFirstName.Value
Records!LastName1.Value = Me!txtSearchlastName.Value
Records!OrigSignUpDate.Value = Date
Records.Update
Records.Close
```

Comment: Thank you. for your help. I am still getting errors. When I use the first solution I get the runtime error 3022 The changes you requested were not sucessful because they would create duplicate values.

Comment: Thank you. for your help. I am still getting errors. When I use the first solution I get the runtime error 3022 The changes you requested were not successful because they would create duplicate values at the Me.Dirty = False line    When I try the second solutuion I get the error 3420 Object invalid or no longer set at the records!NewCustNum.Value = lMaxCustNum line

Comment: For the first, debug your values - the error cannot be false. For the second, adjust code to your actual control names and field names.